# planar Conic Sections plot

Tags: plotting

Among answers of [ConicsAssemblyQuery](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1628842/does-a-right-circular-cone-only-consists-of-pair-of-straight-lines-hyperbolas/1628906#1628906), I posted images that are not pretty. In particular, the parabola is elusive due to large parameter step. Please help.

The program attempts to translate  and rotate a cutting plane ( by varying $ CC, \beta$ respectively ) acting on a cone of given semi-vertical angle $\alpha$. Change of sign in front of sqrt produces cone shell below $xz$ plane that can be Shown together.

```
al = .81; XYZ[x_, bt_, CC_] := {x, Tan[bt] x - CC,  Sqrt[x^2 (Tan[al]^2 - Tan[bt]^2) + 2 Tan[bt] x  CC - CC^2]};
 ParametricPlot3D[ XYZ[x, bt, 0.7], {x, 0, 3}, {bt, 0.85, 3}, Mesh -> {12, 30}]
 ParametricPlot3D[XYZ[x, 1.14, CC], {x, -1.3, 1.3}, {CC, -1.2, 1.2}, Mesh -> {12, 30}]
```

Comment: Does this help PlotPoints -> 50?

Comment: Disjunct parts at $ \epsilon =1$ for parabola to be attached properly and secondly when $z<0$ part of cone surface is together shown, the seam is quite visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post this based on the text of the hyperlink. This was done hurriedly and can be vastly improved (such as plotting conic). Others may wish to do. I am uncertain what the plots shown as graphics aim to do.

```
cone[a_, r_, t_] := {r, r Tan[a] Cos[t], r Tan[a] Sin[t]};
plane[b_, t_, u_, v_] := {0, t, 0} + {u, Tan[b] u, v};
Manipulate[
 Module[{p1, p2},
  p1 = ParametricPlot3D[{cone[\[Alpha], r, t], 
     cone[\[Alpha], r, t] {-1, 1, 1}}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {r, 0, 2}, 
    PlotStyle -> {{Yellow, Opacity[0.5]}}, Mesh -> None];
  p2 = ParametricPlot3D[
    plane[\[Beta], c, u, v], {u, -2, 2}, {v, -1, 1}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Blue, Opacity[0.5]}, Mesh -> None];
  Show[p1, p2, PlotRange -> Table[{-2, 2}, 3], 
   PlotLabel -> Row[{"\[Epsilon]=", Sin[\[Alpha]]/Sin[\[Beta]]}]]],
 {\[Alpha], Pi/6, Pi/3}, {\[Beta], Pi/6, Pi/3}, {c, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [PlotPoints](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotPoints.html) and [MaxRecursion](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxRecursion.html) the results are quite pleasing

```
ParametricPlot3D[XYZ[x, bt, 0.7], {x, 0, 3}, {bt, 0.85, 3}, 
Mesh -> {12, 30}, PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot3D[XYZ[x, 1.14, CC], {x, -1.3, 1.3}, {CC, -1.2, 1.2}, 
Mesh -> {12, 30}, PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

[image]

Comment: The first plot misses out parabola neighborhood when $ \beta \approx  \alpha $. It divides cone into two parts.  The second plot ( parallel planes cutting  and producing ellipses of intersection) is fine.